# REST API Jersey 2.0 NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I am developing a REST API with jersey 2.0 and apache tomcat as web server. In windows operating system when deploying the REST API with eclipse everything is working properly. The problem arrives when trying to deploy the REST API in Ubuntu. I export the war file of the REST API and deploy it in the apache tomcat web server but when I try to access to the service with a POST request, I have the following error:

```
.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() para servlet [jersey-serlvet] lanzó excepción
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.base&#47;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 java.base&#47;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.base&#47;java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
</pre><p><b>causa raíz</b></p><pre>java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INCLUDE_ALL
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$State.&lt;init&gt;(ResourceConfig.java:93)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.&lt;init&gt;(ResourceConfig.java:331)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:481)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:326)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:171)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:363)
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.base&#47;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 java.base&#47;java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.base&#47;java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
* Closing connection 0
```

Why is the REST API working in windows and not in Ubuntu?

UPDATED solution:
An important thing to be sure about is the version of jersey. Be careful having two different versions of jersey because one function could be in both versions and it could be the cause of many errors.

Suggestion to implement REST API: special IDE for web developpers and not just a java one, e.g., Eclipse for web developpers.